# Declaring operator== for a nested template class

Tags: c++, templates, clang, qdoc

I have a following nested template class inside another template class:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    template<typename V>
    struct B {};
};
```

What would be the signature of a non-member `operator==` for the nested type `B`? The following naïve attempt does not work:

```
template<typename T, typename V>
bool operator==(A<T>::B<V> left, A<T>::B<V> right);
```

Clang, GCC and MSVC gives various different errors and/or hints what is wrong such as missing `template` keyword but none of my attempts to resolve it worked out.

Note that this obviously works:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    template<typename V>
    struct B {};

    template<typename V>
    friend bool operator==(B<V> left, B<V> right)
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

**However the reason I need the out of line non-member declaration is to document it using qdoc. The qdoc is using clang to parse the sources and it requires me to provide the declaration of the `operator==` that I have actually implemented in place like just shown.**

[LIVE DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/-5BUFv)

Comment: i would pick the tools based on habits rather than the other way around ;)

Comment: Just for the record, [adding only `template` and `typename` as needed does not fix it](https://godbolt.org/z/ZmMpJu). Deduction still fails.

Comment: Once you add the needed keywords, this question is also essentially the same as "Why does deduction fail here? https://godbolt.org/z/FisYhk".

Comment: @MaxLanghof It seems so. What puzzles me is why does the friend declaration help with the deduction though.

Comment: @Resurrection My uneducated guess would be that it's found through ADL (in the scope of `A<int>`). But that could be wrong.

Comment: This is one of those things you simply cannot declare out-of-line.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not too far off, as you do need the template keyword, but also typename to denote dependent type. A working example would be of the form:

```
template <typename T, typename V>
bool operator==(typename A<T>::template B<V> left,
                typename A<T>::template B<V> right) {...}
```

Although I would suggest instead:

```
template <typename T, typename V>
using operator_type = typename A<T>::template B<V>;

template <typename T, typename V>
bool operator==(operator_type<T, V> left,
                operator_type<T, V> right) {...}
```

as a means of mitigating some of the esoteric syntax required. It's one of those weird one off things where you would expect typename to be enough to denote that ::B is a dependent name of A, but you still need the template keyword, because the parser gets notoriously confused when dealing with `<` and `>`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/8976784) does a pretty nice job of explaining why:

> > After name lookup (3.4) finds that a name is a template-name, if this name is followed by a <, the < is always taken as the beginning of a template-argument-list and never as a name followed by the less-than operator.
>
> Now we are back to the same problem as with typename. What if we can't know yet whether the name is a template when parsing the code? We will need to insert template immediately before the template name, as specified by 14.2/4. This looks like:
>
> `t::template f<int>(); // call a function template`

Answer (score 1):

A direct approach, `typename A<T>::template B<V> left`, does not work as intended because `A<T>::` is a nested-name-specifier, which is a non-deduced context. `T` has to be passed explicitly: `operator==<int>(a, b)`.

To keep `==` usable as a binary operator, an out-of-line non-member declaration can be implemented using SFINAE:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
  template <typename V>
  struct B {
    using ABT = T;
    using ABV = V;
  };
};

template <typename AB>
std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same_v<AB, typename A<typename AB::ABT>::template B<typename AB::ABV>>,
    bool
> operator==(AB left, AB right) {
  return true;
}
```

Full example on godbolt: [click](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgBykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBLSAA6oCoRODB7evgGkyamOAqHhUSyx8VK2mPYFDEIETMQEmT5%2BXIF2mA7pdQ0ERZExcQm29Y3N2W0jvf0lZQkAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMxhyN5YANQmm25OCgTEmKxH2CYaAIJbO3uYh8cEAJ6JmAD650yECmutwe9wImBYiQMYNebg%2BX2YbH2ABUgfczsQvA59ndDgB2Kz3fb7MEQqEvI6wz6MVgvABqqJx%2B3RmII%2BwseIJjKJXlSRmxFiRrwAIsijpyidzecB%2BbThft6ZtxXihWLgSZcSrFWrQeDIUxoRS4dTEXcrJsbmiCOgQCBqdF6N88FRfhTgRKmVabXgFN8FDTvgA3Cmm0jEqkIl4PN7hmn8m2mlHmm0kvXQs2U%2BGx03xiwKm7m0huiXRVCeNXm/aoL7EfUkI6aoUQU37ehUAih5vEPDABAEeYcosXAgrBjEjGYVX3dUqqc60n68nRzOIxMWu7MrF3HHqpUpskwo0R%2BUMokb1nsndFyVhaUJuWJpXXvmm2X149awnKycPDXf4F7hcDxjE0zTXM5rVtZh7R%2BJ0XWOK8PQg71fX9INjhDMNl0jKMM2NSMLBzVdk11fd00PLMCJAF8gQLBCSzLKcKyrOJa2Iet6ybdlW3bfl9i7Hs%2BwHT8hxHfYqDEJQ/1/Wc7jCVkWH%2BBgIH7S9P3Am00C8VlXWORCbXogxaESBAmG/IlVK5bEKTk64bXTdBlmg659lMj9LJwmykxAezHPoZzoj/T9T09FBlm0%2BDdIgJhhTfaIVIitx9jADYAFY3AYZKzK/T8LPdLdrMEWzvIpByvCcitXMfbEPMKryfLKvyKwCtyEPU0KtJhCl9iimLNhFOLOt0zK0oyjY3PM6SfxnO4OEWWhOBS3g/A4LRSFQTg3GsawmWWVZyTMTYeFIAhNFmxYAGsQEkFKADoUrMAA2ABODQHqkA7cQ0J6Hv0ThJCW061s4XgFBADRjtOxY4FgGBEFCiE6DichKDQBH6HiXZDGALgHo0cGsADPA1lpPBMAAdwAeXhTgjpoWgwWIUGIGiQHojCBp3hp3g2eYYh3gp6JtE6E7uF4VG2EECmGFoTmVt4LBoi8YA3DEWhQdF0gsAUoxxDlzW8AuLoA0wdXVswVROi09ZVrkqpAdoPBohrPmPCwQHzjwFhIb4AxgAUEnyapxguZkQQRDEdgKn4QRFBUdQ9d0Lh9CxlAtssfRHdByBFirGp1YAWnA%2BtTEsawuFxXhUGN4guywLPlMqap0hcBh3E8Fo9BCMIBlKIYk7yNIBHGVpchSQeGBmQZykb4XulGJp24mGeugEHpGkn3vp7OXph70bf1%2B72Y%2B8WBRdrWCQ5oWgG9fWjh9lUfwHvzh7JH2TG%2BRxm6NC/7rcEIEhDgHS4PMXgIstDzAuldTYX8uCbDMBoLgB1JCSA0LiFB0h5ocH%2BqQL25cbpPTgSlDQmxNgPVxJsVBONSDLVWrfEGYMIZyyhrDCASAwqJC0sjCAmB8BEFrnoaOwhRDiCjrIWOahAaJ1IGTGsiQuaXw4ItahgNb4Uy0hw1kqAqD30fs/V%2B79pSf2/hobqHg0ZxEAYdEBjDwGLAQJcLA8QG6YOwV7Mw/h8GSCev4FK/hNi4lxO4shVCaGV2BrYBhYDZqkGhnDVGiREZkAoBAeJiSQDY0OprTAhNiak0ptTDWdMGZMxZnrHmHMQ7lL5gLIWDgQ7i0YAQKWMtAYKyVirWgasQ5ayxrrVa%2BBDaOGNqbXg5tLZgkBrbTBq0HZOw5q7a2oCuxe1FosKgvt/Z5KDstWmshw4iOkII8R8dVq6DMMnIwqdS7p1mfXHOiQ86cELlaYuacLDl0rtXWuJt4AnyqLPZw3DW67yTl3YoU89ADxqCC0e%2BR0gbzmEnDoK9ajzxhcimoa8%2BiHwhUitFi8R772xeCzeF8lgrHPsA36ijr60M4Dop%2BL99jAGQMgfYsCbpcF/rwgBWxgGgMhnYhxQxnF/V4Lgp6N1NiSDQf4SQsCzC4gepsfw5zQlAw4PQ8GUTmHwFYSAdhnDkmpPRhEGknAH6MtfiytlHKjo8P/vwpOgj9mR0OWIpQEiE4gHOTIpgcjVnUqUeq1R6iOpaIZXo5lrL2XQK5RAMxCT0aWLMNYnVQqmCOMoAo1xIASE3QCQglK8qzCPUkEA5RN9wmg21YK0gl1Ho3R8eQwJkgHpmBSr45V1LNi0rCZqmx0TYnDqQCapGxrUDmPiAGZAiREiBi4E9b4mwUrfEtVknJmAA75ODoUugxTKClNWlU2WR0T01OFvUydEsmnS1lv0zAitlaq3VkdHpOtFn60GXgYZgMxnICtiHKZ9tHbO3eAs92yz5E%2ByYH7bd2yQ4uuEW60O8hPUnJ0Hmi5xg3kZ2iHctaDz0jqwAPTqRLlYSwHy1pfLwHXX5y8agtzblkEeYKe6IthePGFUL4U4tJUi/5KKsXoqE5i%2BeCK%2B5TDGASveEn%2BOIpPmfSOCjg0qPpZa/YLAFAzv2AGRdUqUrcsdZY/lg6IH1p9Slalua8EEIob43EiCKHfQCZWulA6a3mZiSwthYb2wTqnWatgFrH5aZ02y/TkqpDdQAOoAEkIjYGsQ6vhdGBF7OQ8MI56HJFYb9QGngqm%2B0arUQQDRlZtGae07pqLhnTGTqTRYrYmw011vsZmkVkCuB4xs%2BKn1HinpEPLY9fwUgUokO%2Bu5/tWrvMjvhk1pJKNGtpKJsgRdScCZEy3VsgptN91xBKazdmfNKknf5oLS9GsGmSzva0x97SX3dPBL0z9AzZ6/r1v%2BwDGtgN61mWBiDesPYrKKzBuDu3d27LDll0RMdcveowSnCj1g8MEdzsRp5Rc%2Boo6oxXGjcRvkEYxc3IFLGO6gtbpJ6evGh6yf7mPGo1O95ibnjvenjG2cHxJZxol6L5M8%2BPuSvaZLMFqarXfS1Ua1vssld/eNf8%2BGmba0wjNWbRVYP6wZ6Vn0lWHRXRQvGuJpsatmzqnzeq/PlaNctoL5qOBS6ZTL%2BBZguD4K/qMnlTrUOuuyx6uOeXpAFeg2LkrobreaKq7op3MaDPy4a1OyxkgVe2NIB19XOb%2Bv5qVU9ZBpanqKtegQk3dCIm1tV5ZxVN03opUCbAobqCNCSH8T2sP4T03UrMG3gdHfq6pGcJIIAA).

Answer (score -1):

You can have an inline friend declaration and an outline definition

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    template<typename V>
    struct B
    {
        friend bool operator==(B left, B right);
    };
};

template <typename T, typename V>
bool operator==(typename A<T>::template B<V> left, typename A<T>::template B<V> right)
{
    return true;
}
```

However gcc warns

> warning: friend declaration `bool operator==(A<T>::B<V>, A<T>::B<V>)`
>   declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
>
> note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function
>   template has already been declared and add `<>` after the function
>   name here)

And to fix that warning we would have to forward declare `operator==(B left, B right)` before the definition of `B`, which can only be inside `A`, which would force it to be a friend of `A` also.

Comment: It does not work for me either. It does indeed complain as you point out about non-member being declared (Dan Saks on that topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POa_V15je8Y) but the non-member definition is not actually used. It suffers from the same problem as what was proposed in the OP's comments (now deleted). Forward declaring it as you suggest and adding `<>` to the friend declaration complains about no matching template. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/O5KNu6

Comment: Worth noting is that when trying out with Clang it points to the same underlying issue we are all seeing in all our attempts: `"Cannot infer template type T"`.